# HostListener works incorrectly in case user press Shift button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 6, I write a function to detect if the Ctrl button is pressed:

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown.control')
  onKeydownHandler() {
    console.log('key down control');
  }
```

Each time I press Ctrl button, the log is written in the console.
However, if I press Ctrl+Shift button, this log is not written. Even after I release the Shift button, the log is not written anymore.

Do you have any idea of what happens?

Answer (score 4):

You need to simply decorate it some more.

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown.control')
  @HostListener('document:keydown.shift.control')
  @HostListener('document:keydown.control.shift')
  onKeydownHandler() {
    console.log('key down control');
  }
```

`keydown.control`, `keydown.shift.control` and `keydown.control.shift` are treated as separate, different events.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to ctrl+shift event by using following binding. Not that it will only work if you press control first and then shift.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.control.shift')
  onKeydownHandler(e) {
    console.log('key down control', e);
  }
```

If you want to handle other just add as many decorators as needed.